# Getting strange JSON result when downloading a document

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, sqlcommand

My process is simple, in the view:

```
function DownloadDoc(id) {
    if (!isGuid(id)) {
        ErrorDialog("#MessageDialog", "#lblError", "The value passed is not a valid GUID.", "Invalid GUID");
        return false;
    }
    var form = $('<form method="POST" action="DownloadProjectDocument" target="_blank">');
    form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="fileid" value="' + id + '">'));
    $(body).append(form);
    form.submit().remove();
    return false;
}
```

In the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void DownloadProjectDocument(string fileid)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = new byte[16 * 1024];
        DocumentModel model = Repository.GetProjectDocument(fileid);
        Response.ContentType = model.FileType;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + model.FileName);
        Stream stream = Repository.GetProjectDocumentFile(fileid);
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        stream.Position = 0;
        stream.CopyTo(ms);
        bytes = ms.ToArray();
        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }
```

The document is downloaded but it is also sending a json file for some reason, asking if I want to open or save.  When I open it, it is the JSON result of the entire project record.  I cannot figure out where it is coming from.  Any ideas?

The call to the DB is:

```
public static Stream GetProjectDocumentFile(string id)
    {
        Stream fs = null;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString()))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GET_PROJECT_DOC_FILE"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.UniqueIdentifier)).Value = new Guid(id);
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        conn.Open();
                        adapter.Fill(dt);
                        if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                        {
                            byte[] pdf = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["FileContents"];
                            fs = new MemoryStream(pdf);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    { }
                    finally
                    {
                        conn.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return fs;
    }
```

OK the form is created with the standard:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("ModProject", "EandR", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formModProject" }))
{ }
```

I need this to accommodate the update of the project with:

```
 function UpdateProject() {
    var good = true;
    if ($("#txtEvaluationDeadlineDate").val() === ''){
        $("#txtEvaluationDeadlineDate").addClass("errorClass");
        good = false;
    }
    if ($("#txtSolutionDeadlineDate").val() === ''){
        $("#txtSolutionDeadlineDate").addClass("errorClass");
        good = false;
    }
    if (!good){
        return false;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: $("#formModProject").serializeArray(),
        url: '@Url.Action("ModProject")',
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Errors === "ERROR") {
                ErrorDialog("#MessageDialog", "#lblError", "There was an error encountered, please try again later.", "Error");
                return false;
            } else {
                $("#divDetails").dialog('close');
                var tbl = $("#tblProjects").DataTable();
                tbl.clear();
                tbl.ajax.reload();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I am just serializing the array to get the whole model.  But if I remove the "using" line and last bracket, the process of downloading the doc works just fine.  Very puzzling!  I know there is a way to do a "preventDefault" but how do I do that in the function?

Comment: You should dispose not only the connection, but also the SqlCommand and SqlDataAdapter instances. Not directly related to your question, but may help to avoid memory leaks.

Comment: ^ -> and all the streams.  But then, why have all the streams?  You're reading from the database as a byte array, and writing a byte array to the client - having all the streams in the way seems a bit wasteful

Comment: @Oscar - the "using" statements take care of the disposal...

Comment: Yeah the streams are a but much, but removing them and sending the byte array made no difference - I still get the json file.

Comment: I guess it was staring me in the face = the button should have a type of "button" to prevent the POST of the form.  Oh well, live and learn.